# Android using custom object with ArrayAdapter, and communicating back views

Tags: android, listview, callback, android-arrayadapter, abstraction

There are some similar questions to this but I can't find one that goes as far as I want. I am using a custom class stored in an ArrayAdapter to populate a ListView with linear layouts that I can customise by modifying the class - which is working in that I have a button in each which does exactly what I want. The LinearLayout looks like: [TextView][EditText][Button] and when the Button is clicked, it does some DB stuff with the contents of the EditText. That's all fine.

The problem I have is that I want to (for example) update the text contents of an EditText in 1 layout within the ListView, in my activity rather than in the class where the view is created and the Button listener set and so on. I may also want to say "disable the Button in the second item of the list view" etc..

I've tried a lot of different approaches, passing around contexts or calling methods on the adapter vs on the actual list of objects, making the EditText a member variable with a getter, and I always get either nothing happening or I reach a NullPointerException when looking for the EditText by ID.

Is this even possible? Do I need to create a final variable to hold each EditText and somehow pass this back to the activity or something? I will end up with multiple views within my activity that have the same id, but they'll have been created by separate objects

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is make it so I can abstract my GUIs a bit.  Currently I have 8 activities which are about 90% identical, but I have duplicated code setting up the views in each activity. I want to instead abstract this out into classes where I can say "give me a new text input line with whatever label and I will override the button behaviour" and then refactor down to 1 activity for this task. When a user inputs data in one of the 'rows' then the activity may need to update one of the other rows, (or clear 1 when the back button is pressed etc) which is why I want to be able to call back to a specific view within the layout within the object within the array adapter :D

for example I want to be able to create 3 new textInputLineBuilder objects (probably subclass this eventually) and have them displayed like:

[Name:][NameEditText][Button]

[Stock:][StockEditText][Button]

[Quantity:][QuantityEditText][Button]

here's the (cut down) layout, `activity_row.xml` which the custom object inflates and returns to the ArrayAdapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowLabel"/>    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rowInput"/>    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rowButton"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the relevant code in the activity:

```
public class AnActivity implements UICallBack {
    private ListView listOfInputs;
    private ArrayList<UIElementInterface> listOfUIElements;
    private UIElementsAdapter UIAdapter;
    
    protected void onCreate() {
        listOfInputs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listInputs);
        
        listOfUIElements = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfUIElements.add(new textInputLineBuilder("<label>", this));    //this implements a callback interface
        //add a few more

        UIAdapter = new UIElementsAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), listOfUIElements);
        UIAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listOfInputs.setAdapter(UIAdapter);
    }
    
    public void updateUIState() {
        //I have tried all sorts here
        for (int i=0; i<listOfUIElements.size(); i++) {
            UIAdapter.setTheText("test "+i, i);
        }

        UIAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged;
        listOfInputs.setAdapter(UIAdapter);
    }
}
```

I then have my ArrayAdapter class, `UIElementsAdapter.java` which retrieves the appropriate object from the list and then calls `getRowView` in order to get the object to inflate the layout that will make up this 'row'

```
public class UIElementsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UIElementInterface> {
    private final Context context;

    public UIElementsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UIElementInterface> listOfUIElements) {
        super(context, 0, listOfUIElements);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getItem(position).getRowView(context, parent);   //retrieves the UIElementInterface object aka textInputLineBuilder object
    }

    public void setTheText(String s, Integer position) {
        try {
            getItem(position).setEditText(s);
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and finally I have `textInputLineBuilder.java` which implements the UIElementInterface  (getRowView & setEditText)

```
public class textInputLineBuilder implements UIElementInterface {
    private View convertView;

    public textInputLineBuilder(String label, UICallBack callback) {
        this.labelText = label;
        this.callback = callback;   //used with button onclicklistener
    }
    
    public View getRowView(Context context, ViewGroup parent) {     
        LayoutInflater layout = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = layout.inflate(R.layout.activity_row, parent, false);

        label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowLabel);
        fuzzy = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowButton);
        input = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowInput);
        final EditText inputFinal = input;    //for the button listener.  was trying using input as a member variable for setEditText but that didn't work
        
        label.setText(labelText);
        
        //add onclicklistener for the fuzzy button. works fine
        
        return convertView;
    }
    
    public void setEditText(String s) {
        //I have tried all sorts here, passing in context from various places, passing in layout inflaters etc
        EditText e = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowInput);
        e.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually one modifies the data and then notifies the adapter that the data has changed. That being said, I'm not sure that I understand your approach. Could you add more code?

Comment: yeah this is what is happening in the updateUIState() method in the Activity class - i'm trying to edit the content of an EditText within 1 item of the ArrayAdapter, then notify that the data set has changed

i can't add more code cos this is it!  apart from other stuff in the activity class that is unrelated.

I should have said - the updateUIState() method is called when any of the buttons are clicked and i'm just using it as a test right now

Comment: So UICallback has this updateUIState() method and that's it? I'm asking because I'd like to set up a small app to see what happens and what does not work so far.

Comment: yeah and the callback has a couple of other methods but they're not relevant here.
the callback is only used in the textInputLineBuilder class, currently to do something when the button is clicked.  this part works fine.

for testing, i am just calling updateUIState() directly in the Activity class, so i'm not presently using the callback for that.  I was literally just calling updateUIState() when the activity is created to try and set the text of all the EditTexts, to make sure it worked.  but i can't get it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `updateUIState()`, you currently try to modify the `EditText`s directly by calling `setTheText()`. Using the debugger I was able to see that this works to a certain extent - the `EditText` has the desired value at the end of `setEditText()`. But since the `EditText` is managed by an adapter, setting the text alone does not have the desired effect. If one calls `e.invalidate()` afterwards, the text is displayed correctly, **if** one also skips `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`.

So it's basically possible to modify the `View`s. But it's a bad idea to do it that way.

Instead, you should change the data class. In your case, you need a way to set the desired text (`String`) for the `EditText` in `TextInputLineBuilder`. Then when `getRowView()` is called, this updated text should be used with `EditText input`.

Back to `updateUIState()`: it's correct to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` after modifying the data list, but you do not need to re-assign the adapter to the `ListView`.